# Translation:Bayes Classificator -> precise math?

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes

I want to understand the most simple form of the Bayes classificator [(see here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) but I want to understand it in a really precise, clean, mathematical way.

Math description of the setting:

Let us assume that $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ is a probability space. We endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and assume that $(E, \Sigma)$ is any set with sigma algebra. For a set $A \in \mathcal{B}$ and a map $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ we write $[X \in A]$ (or sometimes just $X \in A$ without the brackets) for $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in a\}$. Occasionally we also abbreviate $[X=a] := [X \in \{a\}]$.

Let $X_1, X_2 : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Z : \Omega \to E$ be measurable functions.
$X_1,X_2$ are called conditionally independent given $Z$ iff. for all sets $A, B \in \mathcal{B}$ and all sets $S \in \Sigma$, we have
  $$P( [X \in A] \cap [Y \in B] ~\mathbf{|}~ Z \in S) = 
P(X \in A ~\mathbf{|}~ Z \in S) \cdot P(Y \in B~\mathbf{|}~Z \in S)$$

We put $E = \{T, F\}$ with $\Sigma = \mathcal{P}(E) = \{\{\}, \{T\}, \{F\}, \{T,F\}\}$ (T stands for 'True' and 'F' for 'False'). We let $Z$ arise as the pullback to $\Omega$ of a ($\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B}-\Sigma-$) measurable map $r : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \{T,F\}$ (r = 'result' that is, a function classifying emails whether they are spam or not or something like this).

*** Assumption for doing the Bayes classifier: $X_1, X_2$ are conditionally independent given $Z$ ***

The target of the Bayes classifier is the following: given a few values $(a_j, b_j) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $y_j \in \{T, F\}$ such that $r(a_j, b_j) = y_j$ for $j=1,...,n$, try to predict for **every** pair $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ whether $r(a,b)=T$ or $r(a,b)=F$.

This is how people describe the setting in practice:

For a given $x=(a,b)$, compute $P(T|x)$ and $P(F|x)$ and predict '$T$' iff. the first value is bigger than the second.

I do not know what these symbols are supposed to mean but I guess that they mean the following: The first symbol means something like $P(Z=T|X=(a,b))$ with the two symbols '$Z=T$' and '$X=(a,b)$' as above (and the second one analogously with $F$).

### Q1: Is this correct?

So now that the symbols make sense we want to compute

$$P(T|(a,b)) = P(Z=T|X=(a,b)) = \frac{P(Z=T \cap X=(a,b))}{P(X=(a,b))}$$

But this seems weird because whenever $X_1, X_2$ are random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ then points usually have probability zero (For example, if they are normally distributed then $P(X = (a,b)) = P_{X}(\{(a,b)\}) = P_{X_1}(\{a\}) \cdot P_{X_2}(\{b\}) = \int_{a}^a ... \cdot \int_{b}^b = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$ [note that setting $S$ to be all of $E$ we get classical independence from the conditional independence]).

### Q2: Why isnt $P(X=(a,b)) = 0$ always?

Now we want to compute this value by using the theorem of Bayes:

$$P(Z=T|X=(a,b)) = \frac{P(X=(a,b)|Z=T) \cdot P(Z=T)}{P(X=(a,b))}$$
$$ = \frac{P(Z=T)}{P(X=(a,b))} \cdot P(X_1=a \cap X_2=b|Z=T)$$
$$ = \frac{P(Z=T)}{P(X=(a,b))} \cdot P(X_1=a|Z=T) \cdot P(X_2=b|Z=T)$$
by the conditional independence.

Ignoring the denumerator and noting that we can effectively estimate $P(Z=T)$ by computing 'nr. of T's divided by $n$', we are left with the computation of the two terms on the right.

In [this article](http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/) the author computes them as follows:
Given a concrete set of observations
$$(a_1, b_1, y_1), ..., (a_m, b_m, y_m)$$ we compute

$$\mu_{1,T} = \text{mean}(\{a_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=T\})$$
$$\mu_{2,T} = \text{mean}(\{b_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=T\})$$
$$\mu_{1,F} = \text{mean}(\{a_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=F\})$$
$$\mu_{2,F} = \text{mean}(\{b_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=F\})$$
$$\sigma_{1,T} = \sqrt{\text{var}(\{a_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=T\})}$$
$$\sigma_{2,T} = \sqrt{\text{var}(\{b_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=T\})}$$
$$\sigma_{1,F} = \sqrt{\text{var}(\{a_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=F\})}$$
$$\sigma_{2,F} = \sqrt{\text{var}(\{b_i | i \in \{1,...,n\} ~\text{is such that}~ y_i=F\})}$$
and put
$$ f(x|\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$

Then 
  $$P(X_1=a|Z=T) = f(a|\mu_{1,T}, \sigma_{1,T})$$
  $$P(X_2=b|Z=T) = f(b|\mu_{2,T}, \sigma_{2,T})$$
and so forth.

### Q3: I guess this is the same issue as above: Assuming that $X_1$ is normally distributed 'on' $[Z=T]$ does not mean that single points have a propability (in particular, why is the propability of a point a value of the density function? This seems weird to me...)?

Cheers & THX in advance,

FW

Comment: Your description is neither clear nor logical.

Comment: Why that? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: For example: (1) A lot of math and notations are introduced in the beginning of your description. But this seems not very helpful for your questions below. (2) Why you assume that $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent normal random variables? Your questions are about machine learning, or more specific, classifiers. The input features are usually discrete, rather than continuous.

Comment: Did you read the question at all? What is the title of the question? The main point about the whole question *is* about the translation wikipedia -> precise math stuff... I do not understand your second point: dependency of variables and whether or not they are continuous are not related at all... plus: Say you have a feature birth year or so: this is not [i.e. should not treated as] discrete! Again: machine learning and discrete vs. continuous variables are unrelated...

Comment: If I dont assume them to be conditionally independent, how should I compute the probability then?

Comment: 1) I know you're looking for precise math description for Baysian classifier.  My point is that the math in the beginning of your question is not very helpful (related) to your question. Concepts like Borel field, in my opinion, are not required to understand or explain Baysian classifiers. You may remove that part, or they may scare others. After all, you could organize all into precice math after accepting answers. 2) It's not about dependent or not, but about the motivation for your assumption. Why you assume $X_1$, $X_2$ in the way specified in your problem? i.e., normal distributions?

Comment: 1) Ill check... I just dont feel well without it: if you say 'random variable' you say 'measurable' and if you say 'measurable' you must say which sigma algebra to take... 2) was it about the word 'normal'? I removed it... the question is about why P(X=single point) is not zero...

Comment: @FabianWerner I got a feeling that the $p$ in wikipedia is density (or pmf for discrete distributions), by looking at the "Gaussian naive Bayes" section.

Comment: @simonzack but in the beginning they write things like p(x|C) and so forth... this means p must be the usual P...

Comment: $x$ is a real number. If $p$ is probability then $x$ needs to be a set. I'm not too sure what $p$ is there, but it doesn't look like probability to me.

Comment: That is precisely the reason why I stick to the math stuff... I think they actually mean P(Z=C_k|X=x) by writing p(C_k|x)...

Comment: $p(x\mid C)$ could be the conditional density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a naive Bayes classifier, you usually need to compute $P(X | C_i)$. In your context, they are $P(X | T)$ and $P(X | F)$. When $X$ is a discrete attribute, both $P(X | T)$ and $P(X | F)$ are easy to estimate based on the training data. However, if $X$ is a continuous attribute, there is a technical difficulty. As you've stated, $P(X = x | F) = P(X = x | T) = 0$. This is highly not expected. To address this problem, the trick is assume that
$$
P(X = x | T) = f(x | \mu_T, \sigma_T)\\
P(X = x | F) = f(x | \mu_F, \sigma_F)
$$
, such that $P(X = x | T)$ and $P(X = x | F)$ won't equal to $0$. $f$ here is the same as the one in your questions. **Note that $P$ here is not a valid probability any more.** In fact, I don't really understand the theoretical reason for choosing Gaussian. But intuitively, if Gaussian is used, the closer the $X$ values is to the mean, the more weight is assigned (i.e., larger $P(X | T)$). This should be expected since in training data, it's very likely that most of X values are near mean, thus more weight.

EDIT:

$P(X  | C_i)$, in my opinion, doesn't have to be a probability. Rather, a value representing weight is enough. When predicting the class label for a new input, we predict the label is $T$ if $\frac{P(T | X)}{P(F | X)} > 1$. Thus in fact the ratio of $\frac{P(X | T)}{P(X | F)}$ matters.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Pr(X|T) follows a Gaussian distribution'? I guess you mean that some function $f:someSet \to \mathbb{R}$ follows a Gaussian distribution. What function f do you mean?

Comment: The statement may be misleading. Let me edit it.

Comment: Fixed. I think I don't clarify your questions and hope to see some other answers.

Comment: To be honest: this answer does not make me happy. I can understand the assumption of independence as an 'accepted' and natural one... To assume, however, that this strange function $ x \mapsto P(X=x|T)$ is even measurable seems very unnatural for me.

Comment: Well. Don't regard $\Pr(X | T)$ as a probability. It is not probability any more. Instead, think it as a weight (maybe $> 1$). The more weight, the more confident that $X$ would occur. As I've stated, only the value of $\frac{\Pr(X|T)}{\Pr(X |F)}$ matters in a naive bayes classifier. So $\Pr(X |T)$ and $\Pr(X|F)$ don't need to be probability. For example, $\Pr(X = x | T) = 5$, $\Pr(X = x | F) = 3$ is equivalent to $\Pr(X = x | T) = 0.5$, $\Pr(X = x | F) = 0.3$ since $\frac{\Pr(X | T)}{\Pr(X | F)}$ are same in both cases..

Comment: In fact, you do, Writing Pr(...) means that a value <=1 *must* occur... please decide: do you want to use Pr(X=x|T) [then the value must be somewhere between 0 and 1] or do you want to use this obscure p (little p) instead of capital P?

Comment: Fixed. I decides to use a capital P to follow your notations and adds an extra statement emphasizing the P is not a valid probability.

Comment: Ok, Im not happy with it but this seems close to the truth. Im gonna accept.